# Changing the player class every turn in a loop

Tags: c#, database, loops, class

I need some kind of class or structure to hold data for 4 players in a simple game. How can I change the player class in every turn during the loop?

I mean something similar to this, where in every turn of a loop some instructions are chaning the data in the class of each player. Is there any effortless way to do this instead of creating many ifs?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player player1 = new Player();
        Player player2 = new Player();
        Player player3 = new Player();
        Player player4 = new Player();

        int playerTurn = 1;

        while(true)
        {
            //some instructions to change the data for example
            //player(playerTurn).x = 1 
        }

    }
}
class Player
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean like a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) of Players..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have numbered variables like this:

```
Player player1 = new Player();
Player player2 = new Player();
Player player3 = new Player();
Player player4 = new Player();
```

What you *probably* want is a *collection*.  For example:

```
var players = new List<Player>
{
    new Player(),
    new Player(),
    new Player(),
    new Player()
};
```

Then you can loop over the list, change specific elements therein, etc.

In your specific case, it looks like you want to access the specific `Player` by an index:

```
//player(playerTurn).x = 1
```

You *can* do this with the list index:

```
players[playerTurn].x = 1;
```

Though if the list is ever sorted, that index is gone.  In this case you might instead use a `Dictionary<int, Player>`.  For example:

```
var players = new Dictionary<int, Player>
{
    { 1, new Player() },
    { 2, new Player() },
    { 3, new Player() },
    { 4, new Player() }
}
```

In this case each `Player` object is always and consistently uniquely identified by that integer value.  And the usage is the same:

```
players[playerTurn].x = 1;
```

Alternatively, you might create a unique identifier on the `Player` *itself*.  For example, suppose it has an `ID` property that you can set:

```
var players = new List<Player>
{
    new Player { ID = 1 },
    new Player { ID = 2 },
    new Player { ID = 3 },
    new Player { ID = 4 }
};
```

In this case you can still use the more generically versatile `List<Player>` structure, and query it to find the specific `Player`:

```
players.Single(p => p.ID == playerTurn).x = 1;
```

There are other collection types you can use.  You could even take it a step further and create a custom `PlayerList` object which internally contains a collection, the current "turn", and other information about the list of players.  But overall the point is that collection types are useful when you have a series of objects.

Comment: I like the dictionary approach! Makes things a little more fool-proof.